# laravel - how to return response from first middleware while using multiple middleware

Tags: php, laravel-5, middleware

i'm using laravel 5.7 with php 7.1 i'm using multiple middleware. I want to return response from my first middleware without executing second middleware how can i achive that?

my route are following:

```
  // Client groups
Route::group(['prefix' => 'clients/', 'middleware' => ['header', 'database']], function () {
  Route::get('/cron', 'FacebookController@cron');
}
```

now i want to return below response from header middleware when sessionid is wrong

return \Response::json(['error' => ['error' => 'Your session id or key is wrong', "code" => 401]], 401);

it return response but also execute database middleware i want to stop execution when return response from header middleware. how can i do that?

Comment: can you show us the database middleware

Comment: i don't want to execute database middlewase and code of my header middleware  is 

if (!$request->headers->has('sessionId')) {
            return \Response::json(['error' => ['error' => "Can't pass session id as null", "code" => 500]], 500);
        }